# xamarin.forms - Visual Studio in Portuguese generating ContentPage derived from ContentView

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

When adding a new ContentPage element in MS Visual Studio (in its version translated to Portuguese) it generates the class derived from ContentView (instead of ContentPage).

**C# code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace XimerinElementsApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class View1 : ContentView
    {
        public View1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="XimerinElementsApp.Views.View1">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

This only happens in Visual Studio in Portuguese. When I install Visual Studio in English, it generates classes correctly inherited from ContentPage. Am I facing a bug related to the language or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: my guess would be that it's a bug in the template.  Use the "Report a Problem" function in VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the problem after the last update (Visual Studio 16.6.2) and the problem no longer happens.